# how to get specific menu items in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a main menu. Each menu item is link to an article.

Now on the complete site there are many places in the components and modules where I need to show two links : Privacy Policy & Portfolio.

Can someone please guide me? I do not want to hard code the links as the item id would differ in production.

Comment: Having looked at this profile and [Bhavik Mulia](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2648304/bhavik-mulia), it seems you have been asking questions and answring them with the other account and upvoting yourself. Flagged for mod attention. Please stop doing this as people who are actually dedicated to this site are simply wasting their time coming up with answers.

Comment: @Lodder someone else noticed it, too. Both accounts have been suspended for 7 days.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try with this

```
<?php

$menuitemid = JRequest::getInt( 'Itemid' );
if ($menuitemid)
{
    $menu = JSite::getMenu();
    $menuparams = $menu->getParams( $menuitemid );
    $params->merge( $menuparams );
}

$propvalue= $params->get('property_name');

?>
```

Comment: do bare in mind that `JRequest` is deprecated in Joomla 2.5 and has been removed in Joomla 3.0+ so if you ever decide to upgrade, you will need to change this code. `JSite::getMenu()` also shouldn't be used for Joomla 2.5+

Answer (score 2):

You could use a database query like so:

```
<?php
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);         
    $query->select('*')
     ->from('#__menu')
     ->where('id = 435 OR id = 466');         
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo '<a href="' . JRoute::_($row->link) . '">' . $row->title . '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Don't forget to change the ID's `435` and `466` to the ID's of your own menu items:

Hope this helps